# Merging 2 tables with data from different queries?

Tags: php, merge, html-table

I currently have 2 tables which look like this:

[image]

The code for these 2 tables looks like this:

```
<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>   
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Mail_ID  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Status  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Datum  </div></th> 
</tr>
<?php 
$j = 0;  
while($objResult2 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery2))  
{  
$j++;  
?> 
<tr>   
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Mail_ID"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Status"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Datum"];?> </div></td>  
</tr>
<?php  
}  
?>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">ID  </div></th>  
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Titel  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Subscribe  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Unsubscribe  </div></th> 
</tr>

<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) : ?>
<tr>  
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["ID"];?><input type="hidden" name="mailid[]" value="<?=$objResult1["ID"];?>"> </div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Titel"];?> </div></td>  
    <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="10"> </div></td>  
    <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="90"> </div></td> 
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>

</table>
```

And the queries and variables look like this:

```
$strSQL1    = "SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail"; 
$strSQL2    = "SELECT * FROM Subscriptions,
(SELECT MAX(ID) as ids, Mail_ID FROM Subscriptions
    WHERE Klant_ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."' GROUP BY Mail_ID) table2
WHERE ID=table2.ids";  
$objQuery1  = mysql_query($strSQL1);
$objQuery2     = mysql_query($strSQL2);
```

Now I would like to merge these 2 tables to look like this:

[image]

I can't get this to work because everything I try mixes everything up due to the 2 loops that are in there. I Hope you guys understand my question, I added as much info and pictures to make everything clear^^ If you still have question just ask them as comment. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Look into [SQL `JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). See example in [MySQL - Join 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230438/mysql-join-2-tables)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a complete solution for you, but it should be a start:

```
SELECT Mail.ID Mail_ID, Mail.Titel, Subscriptions.status, Subscriptions.Datum, Subscriptions.Subscribe, Subscriptions.Unsubscribe
FROM Mail left join Subscriptions on Mail.ID = Subscriptions.Mail_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL Join to form a single SQL query that returns all the data. Then use only one of your loops.

SQL might be something like:

```
SELECT ID, Titel, Subscriptions.* FROM Mail INNER JOIN Subscriptions ON Subscriptions.ID = Mail.ID ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  joins as other  folks already said. By Joining two or more tables You don't need to use multiple while loops and code will be cleaner that way

```
SELECT 
  Mail.ID Mail_ID,
  Mail.Titel,
  Subscriptions.status,
  Subscriptions.Datum,
  Subscriptions.Subscribe,
  Subscriptions.Unsubscribe 
FROM
  Mail 
LEFT JOIN Subscriptions 
ON (Subscriptions.Mail_ID = Mail.ID)
```

One of those join types should work for You: LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN.

HTML should look like:

```
<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>   
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Mail_ID  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Status  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Datum  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Titel  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Subscribe  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Unsubscribe  </div></th> 
</tr>
<?php 
while ($objResult2 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery2))  
{
?> 
<tr>   
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Mail_ID"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Status"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult2["Datum"];?> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Mail_ID"];?><input type="hidden" name="mailid[]" value="<?=$objResult1["Mail_ID"];?>"> </div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Titel"];?> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?=$objResult1["Subscriptions_ID"];?>]" value="10"> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?=$objResult1["Subscriptions_ID"];?>]" value="90"> </div></td> 
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

if You use LEFT JOIN all Mail rows will be visible but if You use INNER JOIN only those Mail rows will be visible which have Subscriptions row associated with it