# Select count with value from different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to count all entries in one table grouped by the user id.

This is the query I used which works fine.

```
select uuid_mapping_id, count(*) from t_message group by uuid_mapping_id;
```

and these are the results:

```
+-----------------+----------+
| uuid_mapping_id | count(*) |
+-----------------+----------+
|               1 |       65 |
|               4 |      277 |
```

Now I would like to display the actual user name, instead of the ID.
To achieve this I would need the help of two different tables.

The table t_uuid_mapping which has two columns:

- uid_mapping_id, which equals uuid_mapping_id in the other table.
- And f_uuid which is also unique but completely different.

f_uuid can also be found in another table t_abook which also contains the names in the column f_name.

The result I am looking for should be:

```
+-----------------+----------+
| f_name          | count(*) |
+-----------------+----------+
|           admin |       65 |
|           user1 |      277 |
```

I am new to the database topic and understand that this could be achieved by using JOIN in the query, but to be honest I did not completely understand this yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Join 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230438/mysql-join-2-tables)

Comment: Learn about how to `JOIN` two mysql tables. The answers you're looking for are all here already.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly:

```
SELECT tm.f_name, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM t_message tm
LEFT JOIN t_abook ta ON (tm.uuid_mapping_id = ta.uid_mapping_id)
GROUP BY tm.f_name
```

Comment: I have improved your syntax.