# Query fields from different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sap-erp

I have this RELATIONSHIP in my database...

[image]

I need to get from TABLE: **MSEG** the **MATNR** field and from the **MAKT** table the **MAKTX** field entering only the **MBLNR** field from my **MSEG** table, IS THIS POSSIBLE????

***In other words, I try to search for MBLNR='426665' and I get the fields from the MSEG and MAKT table.***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Join 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230438/mysql-join-2-tables)

Comment: I don't see clearly the relationship to make with my tables and my fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join the tables as follows

```
SELECT MSEG.MATNR, MAT.MAKTX
FROM MSEG JOIN MAKT ON MSEG.MATNR=MAKT.MATNR
WHERE MSEG.MBLNR = '1337'
```

Replace 1337 with the MBLNR you look for. I assumed it is a String, if its not just remove the ' before and after the number.

Comment: for some reason the query brings me duplicate data, twice the same type of data, I can't see why, could you check it?

Comment: This can be the case if you have the MATNR multiple times in one of the tables. 
Just add a DISTINCT after the select so it looks like:
SELECT DISTINCT MSEG.MATNR, MAT.MAKTX. An alternative is adding a LIMIT 1 at the end of the query.

Comment: AGAIN, you are God, it's DISTINCT works perfect, but the data appears to me out of order!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "out of order" you can use a ORDER BY MSEG.MATNR at the end