# How to find out the desired Output from two tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem :
I have 2 tables Table1 and Table2.
I want to find out Result1 table.
I have tried this with all join but did not get the desired output,Please help me to find out this

Table1 :

```
SubjectId  SubjectName
1           Eng
2           Math
3           Science
```

Table2 :

```
SubjectId   StudentName    Marks
1            Rakesh          70
2            Mohit           60
3            Rakesh          80
```

---

Result1:

```
Subject   StudentName   Marks
Eng       Rakesh         70
Math      Rakesh         0
Science   Rakesh         80
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Join 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230438/mysql-join-2-tables)

Comment: From the result you expect to see I think something like this can work for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9948c8/1

Comment: Assuming 0 is a valid Math Mark you should not display Rakesh's Math Mark as 0 if it is really a *missing* Mark.

Comment: I want to show marks for all Subjects

Comment: @kirchner,Thanks but It does not satisfied my desired Output

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but it looks like the output match your example. Can you edit your question and clarify your needs?

Comment: Can U please paste your query here again in Comment section?@kirchner

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `left join` with filtering:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.marks, 0) as marks
from table1 t1 left join
     tabel2 t2
     on t1.subjectid = t2.subjectid and t2.studentname = 'Rakesh'
```